# which openID and OAuth plugins for WordPress do you recommend?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, oauth, openid

Checking on wordpress.org I saw that there are several plugins for openID and OAuth.
I don't really get a feel from stars and descriptions which are the most robust and popular (have been around for some time and hopefully will be around for longer).

Have you used any of them?
Which do you recommend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said you have many options out there but my preferred one is: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-connect/

It adds support for facebook, twitter, google, wordpress.com and more.

It worked like a charm for me. Hope it helps :)

Comment: This plugin works like a charm. Here are some details on installing it http://giannopoulos.net/2011/12/28/how-to-add-facebooktwitteretc-authentication-on-wordpress/